# Google Analytics: what query string parameter does Google Signals rely on?

Tags: google-analytics, privacy

Google's marketing platform has a feature called 'Google Signals' that makes it possible to track users across devices.  This is possible on Chrome browsers where users have logged chrome into their google accounts (which happens by default if the user logs into a google service).

My question: when the google analytics tracker beacons tracking data back to google, which query string parameter contains the 'cross-device user id'?

Here's what the query string parameters look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Signals will only provide you with data on users with ad personalization turned on in their Google account settings.

The parameters you've referenced is for the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters), which is the foundation for all the different GA implementations (GTM, gtag.js, analytics.js).

I think all the matching is done server-side by Google and possibly a combination of fingerprinting all the devices the google account has signed in with and activity on those accounts, maybe even a pool of GA client IDs & properties.